# How to disable the dpi button of my mouse?

Tags: debian, gnome, usb, mouse

I have a wireless usb mouse (ItWorks WM791) with a `dpi` button that allows me to switch between three mouse speeds.
This button is defective (well... I broke it) and my mouse randomly changes its speed or completely lag (as if the button was continuously pressed), which is very annoying.

**How to disable the `dpi` button?**

I am using Gnome 3 and Debian 10.

Note that `xev` does not recognize this button, and [piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper) does not support support this mouse.

Here is the result of `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3045 Touchpad            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WINTOP     Darty      2.4G Wireless Mouse Mouse   id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard System Control      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V           id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WINTOP     Darty      2.4G Wireless Mouse id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and here is the result of `xinput --list-props 16`:

```
Device 'WINTOP     Darty      2.4G Wireless Mouse Mouse':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (290):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (291):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (292):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (293):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (294):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (295): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (296): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (297):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (298):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (299): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (300): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (301):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (302):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (303):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (304): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (305): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (275): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (276):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (277):    0, 0
    Device Node (278):  "/dev/input/event12"
    Device Product ID (279):    2362, 5768
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (306):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (307):   1
```

What property can I modify to disable the `dpi` change?

Comment: Are you sure that setting isn't internal to the mouse in terms of how it delivers events to the computer?

Comment: Programmable mice allow that, I'm not sure yours is.